Getting Forbidden trying to use Google Directory Services API
I keep getting Forbidden while trying to access Google Directory Services API.  I am attempting to access via a Service Account.
I have enabled Admin API and Directory Services API
I have specified the following scopes:
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member.readonly
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly
I specified the following Roles:
Owner
Service Account Admin
Service Account User
I have enabled Domain-wide Delegation
This is my code:
    var groupEmail = "Group name";

    var service = await GetDirectoryServiceAsync();
    await ListMembersAsync(service, groupEmail);

    private static async Task<DirectoryService> GetDirectoryServiceAsync()
    {
        string serviceAccountKeyFile = "<My JSON file>";

        string[] scopes = { DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryGroup, DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryGroupMember, DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryUser, DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryUserReadonly, DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryGroupMemberReadonly, DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryGroupReadonly} ;

        var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(serviceAccountKeyFile).CreateScoped(scopes);

        return new DirectoryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "Google Groups Manager"
        }
        );
    }

    private static async Task ListMembersAsync(DirectoryService service, string groupEmail)
    {
        try
        {
            var request = service.Members.List(groupEmail);
            var response = await request.ExecuteAsync();
            if (response.MembersValue == null || response.MembersValue.Count == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No members found.");
                return;
            }

            // Print each member's email
            foreach (var member in response.MembersValue)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"- {member.Email}");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error listing members: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

This code with everything I have done gives me "Not Authorized to access this resource".
I have also tried:
var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(serviceAccountKeyFile).CreateScoped(scopes).CreateWithUser("account with admin privledges");

But that just gives me:
"Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested."
Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.
